# I am having difficulty scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll

this is my .css file... dont understand why I cant scroll

```
#root {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}
.titles {
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: #444;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.title-subtitle{
    font-family: times, Times New Roman, times-roman, georgia, serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;color: #444;
    margin-top:0px;

}
```

and then inside my html file I have this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/style.css">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But every time I render or decrease the size of the page vertically, I cant get a scroll bar....

Comment: Please provde a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's best, if your code is executable, e.g. in a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or directly here in StackOverflow as a runnable example.

Comment: Maybe because your CSS file is linked outside `<head>` or you don't have enough content for the body to exceed the browser viewport? Scrolls just fine if the body is tall enough http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygbbOb

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I am using reactjs so its a bit hard to add it on jsFiddle, and Idk it seems to be working but idk why its not working for me, I made sure to add enough content so that it should scroll

Comment: @MichaelCoker I made some changes and now I am seeing two vertical bars, not sure why...

Comment: @MichaelCoker Fixed it, somewhere in the .css I had `position:fixed`. thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

In order to set 100% on `#root`, you also have to set the `html` and `body` to 100%:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```